# EXCEL: Variable external reference Connection not resolving

Tags: excel, reference, external

I have a spreadsheet that contains one summary worksheet and over 300 detail worksheets.  The summary page is used simply as a roll-up of key metrics.

What I need to do now is, using a separate sheet create a dynamic link to the data on the detail sheets, grabbing selected information for an appointment record.

I successfully resolve the worksheet name using VLOOKUP, and have that in a cell.

When I try to take that cell and create a reference to the detail worksheet, the formula doesn't resolve.  No, it hasn't been changed to text.

Here's an example:
Customer # 535018 resolves correctly to 'Aberdeen Gardens'

This is the data that sits in cell C4.

In cell B6 I want Excel to use the data in C4 to construct and resolve the cell C5 on the Aberdeen Gardens worksheet.

I used the following: =" ' " & $c$4 & " '!$c$5"  {spaces are for comprehension}

When I hit enter, what I see in the cell is 'Aberdeen Gardens'!$C$5  which is exactly correct to access the data I want to see.  When I type this reference in without a formula, it resolves and does what I want.

What the heck have I not done right?

Comment: What doesn't work? It sounds like it's working, in your second to last paragraph.  Instead of seeing the formula, do you want to see what's actually in the  'Aberdeen Gardens'!$C$5 cell?  like this: `=Indirect("'"&$C$4&"'!"&"$C$5")`.

Comment: Thanx Bruce!  I don'w what I did wrong when I tried INDIRECT.  All I got was a REF error.  Your version worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use `Indirect()`.

`=Indirect("'" & $C$4 & "'!" & "$C$5")` {I added spaces for comprehension}

Make sure your final reference (the one that's for the cell itself) is also in quotes. I forget sometimes and try `=Indirect("'" & $C$4 & "'!" & $C$5)` and get confused when it doesn't work.  Add quotes!